# How can I change the component of Vue.js with help of object.innerHTML with the click of a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So this is the most simplified version of the program that I am trying to create.
Basically I want to change the display from Component 1 to Component 2 with the click event of of button. Whenever I click the button I want to change from component 1 to component 2 and vice versa.
To create a this program I have used a JavaScript event .onclick, but somehow I don't know why this is not working. My console log is not even showing any error message.please help Thank you

I have also tried using a v-on event but that is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style media="screen">
#inp{
  height:100px;border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src='vue.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='main_area'>
    <button  id='button1' type="button" name="button">Click Here</button>
  <div  id='inp'>

  </div>
  </div>

  <template id="first_comp">
    <div class="FC1">
      <h1>This is component 1</h1>
    </div>
  </template>
  <template id="second_comp">
    <div class="SC1">
      <h1>This is component 2</h1>
    </div>
  </template>


 <script type="text/javascript">

 var elem=document.getElementById('inp');
 var swic=true;
 elem.innerHTML='<comp1></comp1>';
 var btn=document.getElementById('button1');
 btn.onclick=function(){
   if (swic==true) {
     swic=false;
     elem.innerHTML='<comp2></comp2>'
   }
   else {
     swic=true;
     elem.innerHTML='<comp1></comp1>';
   }
 }

 Vue.component('comp1',{
   template:'#first_comp',
   data:function(){
     return{
     }
   },
 })
 Vue.component('comp2',{
   template:'#second_comp',
   data:function(){
     return{
     }
   },
 })

 var vvm= new Vue({
   el:'#main_area',
   data:{

   },
  })
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The console log is not showing any error message

Comment: You have a weird mix of vanilla JS and Vue here - is this intentional? Would it be ok if an answer had no vanilla JS in it?

Comment: I can think of no other solution so I used this. I am very new in web development

Comment: Yes, it would be ok if it does not have Vanilla JS, I just want simplicity